# Inconsistent URL generation behavior

Tags: vb.net

I have tried this question before but got no response. It was probably the way I framed my question, I guess.

Ok, the code below is supposed to work with the this checkbox:

```
   <ItemTemplate>
     <asp:CheckBox ID="recs" runat="server" onclick = "cmd_Click(this)" />
   </ItemTemplate>
```

We implemented check all/uncheck all functionality.

If user checks one checkbox, the code below is supposed to get the value of cell 1 and append to the link below. Then we are able to view the contents of that link.

If the user checks two or more checkboxes, the code grabs the values of cell 1 and append them into the link, separating the links with a comma and again, we are able to view the contents of the links.

The issue is that if we check just one checkbox, it doesn't matter which  checkbox is checked, we get the value for cell 1 and the contents of that link are ALWAYS displayed correctly.

If however, we check more than one checkboxes, some of the contents of the link are blank.

What is most frustrating is that each link works great. Issue comes up with you check more than one link.

Any ideas what could be wrong with code below?

```
Protected Sub GetCheck_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Dim uItems As String = String.Empty
    For Each r As GridViewRow In GridView1.Rows
        If CType(r.Cells(0).FindControl("recs"), CheckBox).Checked Then
            If uItems <> String.Empty Then
                uItems += ","
            End If
            uItems += "http://default.html?gen=" & r.Cells(1).Text & "&mode=print&o=N&s=0.4"
        End If
    Next
Response.Redirect("getPRecs.aspx?p=" & Server.recsEncode(uItems))
End Sub
```

Comment: With "some of the contents of the link are blank" - do you mean like "http://default.html?gen=&mode=print&o=N&s=0.4", like if r.Cells(1).Text returned ""?

Comment: Try `If CType(r.Cells(0).FindControl("recs"), CheckBox).Checked  And r.Cells(1).Text <> String.Empty Then ...`

Comment: Yes, thanks @LosManos for your quick response.

Example, let's assume the value of cell1 is 23514. We stick it into the link. Now it will look something like default.html?gen=23514&mode=print&o=N&s=0.4. When you run it, it displays the content in word form. Works great for one link but if you have 2 or more links, even the contents of that 23514 may now be blank. I can't figure out what the issue is.

Comment: @Olivier, thanks a lot. Still having same issues. This is the weirdest thing I have ever seen!.

Comment: Just a little bit more clue, when more than one checkboxes are checked, and say, 5 links are generated, which in turn opens up 5 documents, one of those documents is 2 pages, one of those pages is blank. In reality, that page is actually just one page. So, the code is adding or generating extra space which may explain the issue I am having. I just don't know how to fix that.

Comment: When you debug, what is the value of r.Cells(1)?  It isn't, like, if fails silently somehow?

Comment: When you debug, what is the value of uItems resp. Server.recsEncode(uItems)?  I was wondering if you get the right result but it is washed somehow.

Comment: @LosManos, the value comes out correctly. And it shows up correctly on the link which makes it even more weird.